# How to write list elements to a file in scala?

Tags: scala

I have a list l2 and I want to write the list elements to the file. I'm doing this:

```
val fw = new FileWriter("src/results.txt", true) ;
for( k <- 1 to l2.length) {
     println(l2(i))
     fw.write(l2(i))
     i+=1
 }
fw.close()
```

But, it does not write anything. Why is that ?

Comment: are you sure that l2 is not empty?

Comment: Yes, it's not empty. That's why I did println above fw.write, it's printing everything correctly. It is a list like this List(1,2,3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `l2` is `List(1,2,3)`, you are calling `.write(int c)` of `Writer` class.

That means `01 02 03` in hex binary is written to file. You can confirm it with `hexdump -C src/results.txt`

To call `.write(String str)`, try `fw.write(l2(i).toString)`.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html

Answer (score 1):

To avoid for-loop you can do it like this:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths
val content = l2.mkString("\n").getBytes
Files.write(Paths.get("src/results.txt"), content)
```